# Why starting time is not calculated or showing blank in videojs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, video.js

i'm using `video.js` plugin where starting time is not calculated which introduces many bugs
while `markin,markout` `seek` etc

**below is my image which shows `starting` time is not calculated(red bordered)**

[image]

**Note:**  The problem is very **RANDOM**,  i'm also using `marker.js`

**Question:** how can i solve it permanently

**below is my code:**

```js
var player;

function initVideojsWithMarker(playerId){
           try{
               if(player) player.dispose();
           }catch(e){}
    
            try {
                player = videojs(playerId);
                player.markers({
                    markerTip: {
                        display: false,
                        text: function (marker) {
                            return  marker.text;
                        }
                    },
                    breakOverlay: {
                        display: false,
                        displayTime: 3,
                        text: function (marker) {
                            return  marker.text;
                        }
                    },
                    markers: []
                });
            } catch (e) {}
}


 var playerVideo = `<video id="demoVideo" disablepictureinpicture="" controlslist="nodownload" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"  controls muted data-setup="{ "inactivityTimeout": 0}">
         <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/ogg"></source>
   </video>`;

$('#videoPlayerWrapper').html(playerVideo);

initVideojsWithMarker('demoVideo');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-markers/0.7.0/videojs-markers.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-markers/0.7.0/videojs.markers.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />






<div id="videoPlayerWrapper">


</div>
```

Comment: Does this happen even here in the snippet? I personally can't reproduce. Does this always happen with the same video?

Comment: if you are using jQuery maybe you need to wrap your code in `$(document).ready()`, I tried to reproduce your issue but it seems to be working fine with this code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `setTimeout` with little delay:

```js
function initVideojsWithMarker(playerId) {
  try {
    player = videojs(playerId);
    player.markers({
      markerTip: {
        display: false,
        text: function(marker) {
          return marker.text;
        }
      },
      breakOverlay: {
        display: false,
        displayTime: 3,
        text: function(marker) {
          return marker.text;
        }
      },
      markers: []
    });
  } catch (e) {}
}


var playerVideo = `<video id="demoVideo" disablepictureinpicture="" controlslist="nodownload" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"  controls muted data-setup="{ "inactivityTimeout": 0}">
         <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/ogg"></source>
   </video>`;

$('#videoPlayerWrapper').html(playerVideo);

setTimeout(function() {
  initVideojsWithMarker('demoVideo');
}, 10)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-markers/0.7.0/videojs-markers.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-markers/0.7.0/videojs.markers.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />






<div id="videoPlayerWrapper">


</div>
```

Comment: what is the actual cause of the problem , can you please mention it. it is very random problem

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say for sure without being able to reproduce, but waiting for the player to be ready before setting the source could help. This is a very old version of Video.js, so it's not fresh in my mind if this was ever an issue back then, but it could be there's a race condition with the browser loading the source while the DOM is modified which might explain it being so intermittent.

```
var player = videojs('demoVideo', {inactivityTimeout: 0});
player.ready(function() {
  player.src({
    src: "https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm",
    type: "video/webm"
  });

  player.markers({...}); 
]);
```